# Automatically advance to next field in HTML form without changing tab behaviour

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, phone-number

I have five textboxes in same order as mentioned below with IDs

1. txtFirstName
2. txtLastName
3. txtEmailAddress
4. txtTelcode
5. txtTelephoneNumber

I want tab functionality for phone numbers (txtTelcode and txtTelephoneNumber).

Maxlength of textbox txtTelcode is 5. Below is the functionality required.

When user fill txtTelcode, then after entering 5 digits tab should be automatically shifted to next textbox txtTelephoneNumber.

I used the below code which is working fine but I am facing one issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#' + telcode).keyup(function () {
        if ($.trim($('#' + telcode).val()).length == "5") {
            $('#' + txtTelephoneNumber).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that if there are already 5 digits in txtTelcode then when the user tabs into txtTelcode this function automatically advances them to txtTelephoneNumber without stopping in txtTelcode. This is not what I want to happen; instead I need to be able to tab into txtTelcode even when it is complete. How can I modify my code to fix this, or how else can I implement this?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand the last sentence: are you saying that if you tab into a full txtTelcode then it's moving you to txtTelephoneNumber and you don't want it to, or that you do want it to automatically advance to txtTelephoneNumber but that's not happening?

Comment: Hi, your first understanding is correct. If I tab into txtTelcode then tab should be shifted to txtTelcode only.
but currenlty tab is shifting towards txtTelephoneNumber.

Comment: As a UI note on this question, I hate auto-advancing forms. They invariably get the auto-advance wrong when tabbing, shift-tabbing, correcting entries, etc. Disrupting user interface paradigms should be for giant companies like Apple or Google or very specific scenarios.

Comment: Auto-advance always results in bad user experience for non experienced users (experienced with that specific form). The user doesn't know in-advance whether your site uses it and on what fields which results in worse user experience, contrary to what you are trying to achieve (this goes with other common very-bad-for-user things like filtering input which are for some reason widely thought to be good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified my own code as mentioned below. I prevented my code to run if Tab is pressed by getting e.keyCode.

For shift + tab functionality I prevented my code to run if Shift is pressed by getting e.keyCode.

```
$('#' + telcode).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 16) {
                if (e.keyCode != 9) {
                    if ($.trim($('#' + telcode).val()).length == "5") {
                        $('#' + txtTelephoneNumber).focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This code is working fine.

Comment: For Shift + tab functionality we need to prevent our code to run if shift is pressed.
So we can use one more check as mentioned below

 $('#' + telcode).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode != 16) {
                    if (e.keyCode != 9) {
                        if ($.trim($('#' + telcode).val()).length == "5") {
                            $('#' + txtTelephoneNumber).focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });